# Django-Leaflet - set dynamic layers

Tags: django, leaflet, tiles, esri-leaflet, esri-oss

I want to set DynamicMapLayer to my django-leaflet template. Maybe anyone knows how can I do it?

I prefer this like `L.esri.dynamicMapLayer`, maybe `L.esri.featureLayer` from `esri-leaflet.js` plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem. I forgot  about `'PLUGINS'` at settings.py.

```
'PLUGINS': {
    'esri-leaflet': {
        'css': '',
        'js': 'libs/esri-leaflet/dist/esri-leaflet.js',
        'auto-include': True,
    }
},
```

Then add it to template:

```
<head>
    ...
    {% leaflet_js plugins="ALL" %}
    {% leaflet_css plugins="ALL" %}
</head>
<body>
    ....
    L.esri.dynamicMapLayer({
        url: 'http://mytilesURL',
        ...
    }).addTo(map);
    ....
</body>
```

Source: [django-leaflet docs](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-leaflet)